# I am able to upload to AWS S3 from my localhost, but not from my AWS Elastic BeanStalk instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS. I have developed spring boot application to upload files in S3 bucket.

I have created IAM user and assign AmazonS3FullAccess. I am using that user accessKey and accessSecret in my spring boot application to upload file and its working fine in my localhost but its not working in AWS Elastic BeanStalk instance. I am getting permission denied exception message.

Comment: Can you check service groups of S3 and BeanStalk for accessing each other?

Answer (score 1):

In the *Configuration* of your Elastic Beanstalk application, in the *Security* section, there should be an *IAM instance profile* configured.

Once you've identified the role that it is using, you need to open the [Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home) console, navigate to the list of Roles, find the role, and add a new policy to it. The easiest solution is to add an inline policy. Give it permissions to upload files to the bucket and it should start working. There shouldn't be a need to restart the server.

Comment: Thank You. As per your suggestion i have checked and in Elastic Beanstalk security section found IAM instant profile is aws-elasticbeanstack-ec2-role and in IAM roles section under elasticbeanstack-ec2-role AmazonS3FullAccess policy has attached. I have also added inline policy still i am getting Permission Denied error.

Comment: Is your application using the AWS SDK or something else to perform the S3 operations? Depending on the SDK, you may have to tell it to fetch credentials from the metadata server.

Comment: Hey @stefansundin I face the same issue, and use aws-sdk for javascript/nodejs. Could you tell me more about the metadata server?

Comment: Hi Omar. It appears that the nodejs SDK automatically fetches credentials from the metadata server according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-iam.html.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was to add permission policy to my elastic beanstalk role.

[image]